# How to erase all duplicate elements in a list Scheme?

Tags: scheme

My attempt was,

```
(define (remove-dup lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((null? (cdr lst)) (car lst))
        ((equal? (car lst) (car (cdr lst))) (remove-dup (cdr lst)))
        (else (cons (car lst) (remove-dup (cdr lst))))
        )

  )
```

My list was `(a b c a a c c c )`
What I want is `(a b c)`. Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Try to go through step by step what happens on the first call - in what `cond` branch do you end up?

Comment: @Anders Lindahl: I tested it with my debugger, but I couldn't figure out where I missed. It looked reasonable to me though. Could you give a few more hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd approach this by looping with a second list that you build up of seen elements.  I'll feel bad for giving this to you if this was homework though - it's more important to understand how recursion works than to just have the right answer.

```
(define (remove-dup ls)
  (let loop ((ls ls) (seen '()))
     (cond
       ((null? ls) '())
       ((memq (car ls) seen) (loop (cdr ls) seen))
       (else (cons (car ls) (loop (cdr ls) (cons (car ls) seen))))))
```

**Updated** to accommodate your comments - this probably isn't the cleanest solution but should give you an idea of how it might work.

```
(define (rdup ls)
  (let loop ((ls ls) (current #f)) ; this is bad coding style, a "magic" variable you don't expect to see in your list
     (cond
       ((null? ls) '())
       ((null? (cdr ls)) (if (eq? (car ls) current) '() ls))
       ((eq? (car ls) (cadr ls)) (loop (cdr ls) (car ls)))
       ((eq? (car ls) current) (loop (cdr ls) current))
       (else (cons (car ls) (loop (cdr ls) (car ls)))))))
```

Comment: @A Lee: Thank you. Don't worry, this was not my homework. Furthermore, I'm looking for a recursive solution instead of iterative one since the reason I moved to Scheme is to improve my recursive thought.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I'd definitely recommend stepping through with a debugger (or tracing with pencil & paper as I used to have to do it in college) to better understand how the recursive calls get built up within the loop and how its arguments change with each call.

Comment: @A Lee: My answer was very very close, one step from the answer I think. However, I was still not be able to figure out. By the way, your answer was slightly different than the one I expected. For the example above, the result is correct. However, for `a b a a c c`, it should return `a b`, instead of `a b c`. It was my fault since I did not state it clearly.

Comment: Ah, so `'(a b a b a b)` should return `'(a b a b a b)`?

Comment: @A Lee: Oh yeah, you bet! I would love to see a recursive solution though. Would you mind? cause without recursion, I don't feel motivated to learn Scheme.

Answer (score 2):

R5RS + SRFI1

```
(define (remove-duplicates lst)
    (fold-right (lambda (f r)
             (cons f (filter (lambda (x) (not (equal? x f))) r))) '() lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SRFI 1 you can use directly `delete-duplicates` or `delete-duplicates!`: http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#delete-duplicates