# Scheme: Remove duplicated numbers from list

Tags: list, scheme, duplicates

I wrote this code to create a list from **en** number of arguments given

```
(define (create-list . e)
   e)
```

But I need it to remove any duplicated numbers from the list within this block itself.

I have tried and searched for hours and can't find a solution without placing dozens of lines of code on other blocks.

For example let's say my input is

```
(create-list . 2 2 3 5 5 )
```

I need the list created to be '(2 3 5) and not '(2 2 3 5 5 )...

The order of the numbers doesn't matter.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8651932/450148

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you need to do something like:

```
(define (create-list . e) (dedupe e))
```

I can think of a really simple but probably inefficient way to do this:

```
(define (dedupe e)
  (if (null? e) '()
      (cons (car e) (dedupe (filter (lambda (x) (not (equal? x (car e)))) 
                                    (cdr e))))))
```

If you can't use existing functions like `filter`, you can make one yourself:

```
(define (my-filter pred ls) 
  (cond ((null? ls) '())
        ((pred (car ls)) (cons (car ls) (my-filter pred (cdr ls))))
        (else (my-filter pred (cdr ls)))))
```

Comment: would it be possible to create the same code with cdr/car/cons and primitive procedures only? (No filter/head/tail)

Comment: Yes. In fact, `head` and `tail` are already just `car` and `cdr` respectively (too much Haskell on my mind).

Comment: Also, note that my syntax may be a little off--I've only been using Haskell much recently and I only ever used stk, which is an outdated scheme interpreter.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't used to it. Just checked the edited answer. Thank you!

Comment: In general, `filter` takes a list and a predicate (a function that returns true or false) and returns a list containing only the elements for which the predicate returned true. You can think of it as a `select-where`.

Comment: @spacing: There is a good reason you weren't used to it--using `head` and `tail` don't come from Scheme, they come from another language I've been using.

Answer (score 2):

This one is faster:

```
(define (remove-duplicates l)
  (cond ((null? l)
         '())
        ((member (car l) (cdr l))
         (remove-duplicates (cdr l)))
        (else
         (cons (car l) (remove-duplicates (cdr l))))))
```

But even better, 
mit-scheme provides delete-duplicates, which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient (traversing the list once) way to do this is to define a function which goes through the list element-by-element. The function stores a list of which elements are already in the de-duped list.

An advantage of this solution over @Tikhon Jelvis's, is that the list elements don't need to be in order, to be deduplicated.

Given a function `elem`, which says if `a` is an element of `l`:

```
(define (elem? a l)
      (cond ((null? l) #f)
            ((equal? a (car l)) #t)
            (else (elem? a (cdr l)))))
```

We can traverse the list, storing each element we haven't seen before:

```
(define (de_dupe l_remaining already_contains)
   (cond ((null? l_remaining) already_contains)
         ((elem? (car l_remaining) already_contains) (de_dupe (cdr l_remaining) already_contains))
         (else (de_dupe (cdr l_remaining) (cons (car l_remaining) already_contains)))))
```

Note: for efficiency, this returns the elements in reverse order

Comment: Does my version need the elements in any sort of order? As far as I know, it doesn't.

Comment: @Tikhon Jelvis: It looked like it; I can't get it to return proper values, though. Example: "(create-list 3 5 4 3 4 6)" returns "(3 3)"

Comment: That wasn't because of order, it was because I accidentally left out a not in the filter's predicate. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (delete x)
(cond
((null? x) x)
((= (length x) 1) x) | ((null? (cdr x)) x)
((= (car x) (cadr x)) (delete (cdr x)))
(#t (cons (car x) (delete (cdr x))))
)
)
```