# How to duplicate a list in scheme?

Tags: scheme

the following code removes duplicate in a list which I got from abo-abo's [answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382296/scheme-remove-duplicated-numbers-from-list).

```
(define (remove-duplicates l)
  (cond ((null? l)
         '())
        ((member (car l) (cdr l))
         (remove-duplicates (cdr l)))
        (else
         (cons (car l) (remove-duplicates (cdr l))))))
```

I am just starting learning scheme, how can I duplicate each item in the list for example `(5 6 7 8 9 9 10 11 11)` will become `(5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 9 9 10 10 11 11 11 11)`?

Comment: as an off-topic aside, the best way to learn Scheme is to read SICP and doing all of the exercises. I'm doing it right now, and it's really rewarding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicit recursion with `append`and `list`, and `foldr` version just with `cons`:

```
(define (dup lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      '()
      (append (list (car lst) (car lst))
              (dup (cdr lst)))))

(define (dup2 lst)
  (foldr (λ (x xs) (cons x (cons x xs)))
         '()
         lst))
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have a list `l` you can do the following to have a duplicate of the first item at the beginning of a resulting list,

```
(cons (car l) l)
```

or equivalently

```
(cons (car l) (cons (car l) (cdr l)))
```

This results in the following solution:

```
(define (duplicate l)
  (cond ((null? l)
         '())
        (else
         (cons (car l) (cons (car l) (duplicate (cdr l)))))))
```